# Question about arrow in diagram

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, arrows

how i can write using latex to find this: [image]

but with long arrows

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at either the xy package or the tikz-cd package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite easy with `tikz-cd`.

1. The first bit is the arrow direction: `d` for “down”, `r` for “right” and so on.
2. The label on an arrow is by default on the left side (in the arrow direction); with `swap` we place it on the other side
3. Similarly, `shift left` refers to a movement towards the left side of the arrow (in the arrow direction); `shift right` does the same in the other side.
4. The default value of `row sep` is 1.8em, while `column sep` is 2.4em; play with them until you're satisfied.
5. The `^{\vphantom{\prime}}` is used in order to have the two iotas at the same level.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em,column sep=4.5em]
C_{p-1}(X) \arrow[dr,"K_{p-1}"] &
  C_{p}(X) \arrow[l,swap,"\partial"]
  \arrow[d,shift right=.3em,swap,"\iota^{\vphantom{\prime}}_{p}"]
  \arrow[d,shift left=.3em,"\iota'_{p}"]
  \arrow[dr,"K_{p}"]
\\
& C_{p}(X\times[0,1]) &
  C_{p+1}(X\times[0,1]) \arrow[l,swap,"\partial"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the older Xy-pic package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R=3em@C=4.5em{
  C_{p-1}(X) \ar[dr]^{K_{p-1}} &
    C_{p}(X) \ar[l]_{\partial}
    \ar@<-.3em>[d]_{\iota^{\vphantom\prime}_{p}}
    \ar@<.3em>[d]^{\iota'_{p}}
    \ar[dr]^{K_{p}}
  \\
  & C_{p}(X\times[0,1]) &
    C_{p+1}(X\times[0,1]) \ar[l]_{\partial}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

The syntax is a bit different, but the ideas are the same.

[image]

Comment: It makes me an error with this usepckage

Comment: @Vrouvrou What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Im using texmaker

Comment: @Vrouvrou Texmaker is just the editor; what's the first line  in the `.log` file you get after compiling? You can try the Xy-pic version, but I'd recommend using `tikz-cd` if possible.

Comment: l/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/local/t

Comment: @Vrouvrou Well, your TeX distribution is pretty old.

Comment: and how i can write please ?

Comment: Yessss thank you, please can i obtaine an other tex distribution without loose my doccument in this latex ?

Comment: You can install TeX Live 2014 without a problem. Your document is just a text file, and you won't lose it. Just tobe quite sure, save the .tex file and the resulting .pdf you have at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You also can easily do such an homotopy diagram with the `psmatrix` environment (from the `pst-node` package. The syntax is different from `tikz-cd`: you first describe the matrix of nodes, then the connections between these nodes. The nodes can have names, but you can use their `i,j` position in the matrix.

It can be compiled with `pdflatex` if you set the switch `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX)`or`--shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX):

```
\documentclass[pdf]{report}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{arrows=->, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=3pt, colsep=1.2cm, rowsep=1.8cm}
\begin{psmatrix}
  C_{p-1}(X) & C_p(X) \\%
   & C_p(X × [0,1])&C_{p + 1}(X × [0,1])
%
   \ncline{1,2}{1,1}\nbput{∂} \ncline{2,3}{2,2}\nbput{∂}
   \ncline{1,1}{2,2}\naput[labelsep =0pt]{K_{p-1}} \ncline{1,2}{2,3}\naput[labelsep =0pt]{K_p}
   \ncline[offset=- 0.8ex]{1,2}{2,2}\nbput{i_p}\ncline[offset=0.8ex]{1,2}{2,2}\naput{i'_p}
\end{psmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it makes me error, i'm using texmaker

Comment: Did you try the `latex + dvips` way? I guess the mentioned switch is not enabled on your system. You  should configure TeXmaker (Options menu) with this line for pdflatex:`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`.